# Using Spry to dynamically change image - Issues with Chrome, not with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, spry

I've been reworking a Spry demo about reporting Sports scores. 
All works fine with being able to change the score in the XML file, which then updates the webpage without the audience having to update their webpage to get the latest score.

Using the following to keep it checking the XML for score updates:

```
var dsCricket = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("cricket.xml", "innings/stats", { useCache: false, loadInterval:5000 });
```

My problem happens when attempting to change an image being displayed, the correct image loads, but when viewed in Google Chrome, the image seems to be reloading approximately every 20 seconds causing it to flash. This is not a problem in Firefox and it all works as intended.

Is there a reason why this is only happening in Chrome and any suggestion to prevent the image from flashing?

Thanks